# How do I change the width of a list input page?

Tags: 2007, list, column, categories

I have a SharePoint list. When you select "New" to add an item, some of the categories are extremely long (they're actually questions) and cause you to have to scroll from left to right to read the entire question.
How do I adjust the width of this?

I am a low-level user of SharePoint Designer - and belong to a corporation that locks a lot of system access. We can change most items, but we can't get behind the scenes beyond Designer!

I would also ask you to give me detailed steps since I don't use Designer very often! Usually just to write workflows!

Thanks, Rachel

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take is:

1. Navigate to the form in IE/Firefox. If in IE hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools. If using FireFox, download the Firebug addon and then hit F12.
2. Use the selector tool to highlight the field that is having a short input.
3. Note the class, specifically one that shows the width.
4. Create a CSS file that overrides that style.
5. Upload it to a Sharepoint Document Library and note the URL.
6. Navigate to the list form and append &pageview=shared&toolpaneview=2 to the URL.
7. Add a content editor web part to the form and in the Content link field paste the URL to the CSS file.
8. The form fields should now be your desired length.

Comment: ok, wow, that's way above my head!
I can't figure out the field name that's too short - in CSS there's hundreds of choices as I scroll through the page, I can't identify the "column" field.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the creator made 10 questions as the columns - so in a document library you'd have filename, created by, created date, etc.
In this one she's made 10 questions as the categories of the list. About 6 of them are too wide.

Comment: When I look in the F12 CSS view you recommended, there's actually hundreds of fields and I don't know how to tell them apart :(

Comment: If the field labels are the issue, then the CSS class to look for and overide is probably ms-formlabel. If it is an actual text box you need to override, then that is typically ms-long.